# Why in a two's complement system does the expression x &= (x - 1) delete the rightmost bit?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Sorry, another K&R question! "Exercise 2-9: In a two's complement number system x &= (x - 1) deletes the rightmost 1-bit in x. Explain why."

I worked this out and (I guess incorrectly) determined that more than the rightmost 1-bit will be deleted. I know that in two's complement, the negative number is formed by taking the complement and adding 1. Then to perform subtract the negative number is added, and the high-carry bit is discarded.

So let's take x = 8, and I'll use 2 bytes for brevity:

x = 00001000

So to do x - 1 we actually add -1? So the complement of 1 is:
11111110
and adding 1 we get
11111111

Then we have:
00001000
+11111111
= 00000111

which is the answer we expect. Next we're going to & that result with x, and assign it back to x:
00001000
&00000111
= 00000000

in which it appears I've made some sort of mistake because more than the right-most bit got deleted.

Comment: When there is only one `1` bit, then the leftmost is the same as the rightmost, is not? Try your "test method" with 12 (`00001100`).

Comment: When you want to tell your friends about this, use `clears the lowest set bit` instead of `deletes`... The bit is still there. It's value has changed from '1' to '0'... It has not be 'deleted'...

Comment: @Fe2O3 lol thanks Rust. Then they might not realize how green I am. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You worked it out perfectly. I think you just misunderstand what is meant by "the right-most 1-bit" (you keep just saying "rightmost bit", omitting the "1-bit" from the original prompt).

`00001000` only has a single `1` bit. After the operation, that `1` bit is gone; as you showed, you're left with `00000000`. It's doing exactly what it says on the tin, finding the `1` that is closest to the right hand side and clearing it (all the `0` bits to the right of that `1` bit remain unchanged, as do all the bits to the left of it, whether they are `0` or `1`). If you work out the same math with `00110000`, you'll find the result to be `00100000`, removing the rightmost `1`-bit, flipping it to a `0`. `0111` becomes `0110`, `0110` becomes `0100`, etc.

Comment: Wow, Ok, thank you ShadowRanger. I seem to get confused when I'm really tired.  :D  I think I thought it meant the all the way to the right bit, and it was a procedure that would leave it unchanged if the lowest order bit was 0.